# Spring Kafka - Exception is causing Manual Immediate acknowledgment to be rolled back?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Can someone please help me understand why a message offset that is manually and immediately committed is re-processed by the KafkaListener when an exception occurs?

So I'm expecting the following behaviour:

1. I receive an event in Kafka Listener
2. I commit the offset
3. An exception occurs
4. I'm expecting that message not to be reprocessed because the offset was committed.

Not sure if my understanding is correct? Or does Spring rolls-back the manual Acknowledgment that we do in case of exception?

I have the following Listener code:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"${acknowledgement.topic}"}, containerFactory = "concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void onMessage(String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws InterruptedException {
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();

    throw new Exception1();
}
```

And the concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory code is:

```
    @Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    kafkaProperties.getConsumer().setEnableAutoCommit(false);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    return concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the default error handler treats any exception as retryable by default, regardless of whether its offset has been committed.

You should either not throw an exception, or tell the `DefaultErrorHandler` which exception(s) should not be retried.

```java
/**
 * Add exception types to the default list. By default, the following exceptions will
 * not be retried:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link DeserializationException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MessageConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MethodArgumentResolutionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link NoSuchMethodException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ClassCastException}</li>
 * </ul>
 * All others will be retried, unless {@link #defaultFalse()} has been called.
 * @param exceptionTypes the exception types.
 * @see #removeClassification(Class)
 * @see #setClassifications(Map, boolean)
 */
public final void addNotRetryableExceptions(Class<? extends Exception>... 
exceptionTypes) {
```

Comment: I haven't tried this use case that I'm questioning here outside Spring (using only pure Apache Kafka Jars). But do you know if we don't use Spring and use native Kafka Libraries, If I commit the offset and then have an exception, does the message gets picked again when I do the next poll?

Comment: The native API `poll()`s the consumer so there is no way to "throw an exception". Kafka maintains 2 offsets - the position and the committed offset. The next poll fetches the next record after the last one in the previous poll. Spring's default error handler (with default configuration) performs seeks so that the failed record is re-fetched.